# pyspark how to save and load one vs rest classifier logistic regression

Tags: pyspark, logistic-regression, apache-spark-ml

I am using pyspark 2.4.5 I have a problem with saving and loading one vs rest classifier

Below is the code

```
 from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression, OneVsRest
 start=time.time()
 lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, tol=1E-6, fitIntercept=True)
 # instantiate the One Vs Rest Classifier.
 ovr = OneVsRest(classifier=lr)
 # train the multiclass model.
 ovrModel = ovr.fit(df)
 end=time.time()     

 ovrModel.save('s3://one_vs_Rest_model')
```

while loading the model I give

```
 lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, tol=1E-6, fitIntercept=True)

 # instantiate the One Vs Rest Classifier.
 ovr = OneVsRest(classifier=lr)
 ovr_mdl=ovr.load('s3://one_vs_Rest_model')
```

I get error as

```
'requirement failed: Error loading metadata: Expected class name 
org.apache.spark.ml.classification.OneVsRest but found class name 
org.apache.spark.ml.classification.OneVsRestModel'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/util.py", line 362, in load
return cls.read().load(path)
 File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/util.py", line 300, in load
java_obj = self._jread.load(path)
 File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
 File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco
raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'requirement failed: Error loading metadata: Expected 
class name org.apache.spark.ml.classification.OneVsRest but found class name 
org.apache.spark.ml.classification.OneVsRestModel'
```

Comment: see the official [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.OneVsRest)
  
model2 = OneVsRestModel.load(model_path) you have to use Model class to load the path instead of reinitialize the OneVsRest Model

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Will test definitely if not now later point in time. This is really helpful. If any doubts will get back to you again

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have saved a OneVsRestModel object, and you are trying to load a OneVsRest object.

To load the saved model you can just do this:

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import OneVsRestModel
ovr_mdl = OneVsRestModel.load('s3://one_vs_Rest_model')
```